# Increase Brightness of image button on button click event

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i am working on a website.In that website i have taken an image button.now i want that when a user click that image button on run time,the image button stated to glow or the brightness of that image button gets increased,and on again click it should get back to normal. 
On clicking the button i want to pass the value as 1/0 in my status column of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the css on hover of the button

```
    <style type="text/css">
            .abc
            {
                width: 100px;
            }
            .abc:hover
            {
                -webkit-filter: brightness(150%);
            }
    </style>

 <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" CssClass="abc" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/NewImages/logoBlack.png" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62bCB/

hope this helps you .

Comment: can i get the same functionality on button click??? and on clicking the button i want to pass 0/1 value in my status column of database

Comment: yes. You can use Button1.CssClass = "abc";  in click event of code behind code

Comment: rajeev please check out the question above..i have edited few things in that.